# How to configure a newer version of Supervisord to start on system boot in Ubuntu 12.02?

Tags: linux, upstart, init.d, daemon, supervisord

How do you configure a newer version of supervisor to start on system boot in Ubuntu?
Some distributions simply lag behind in their repositories.

When I use easy install (as recommended by default on the supervisor website) I only get the binary installed but it is not daemonized.

http://supervisord.org/installing.html

There's a previous old post that mentioned creating either an upstart or a systemd script that has multiple people try different things to get it to work but there's no definitive answer.

[How to automatically start supervisord on Linux (Ubuntu)](https://serverfault.com/questions/96499/how-to-automatically-start-supervisord-on-linux-ubuntu)

Comment: Whenever possible, should should use packages provided by your distribution's repository. If you remove the version you installed and then reinstall using apt, you will not have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

While is true that the documentation lists using easy_install to set up supervisor it also shows other methods like using a package. The limitation with packages is that you become dependent on the distribution lagging behind the development cycle of supervisor. This is a workaround for that which relies on adding an external repository to your distro. If you believe this is a no go then consider upgrading your distribution. If all you're interested in is a System V init.d script go to the bottom of the post. There's a link to a community supported list of scripts for different distros including Ubuntu.

After some research these are the steps I found install supervisor then deamonize it and add a default supervisord.conf file in Ubuntu 12.04 which has an old version of supervisor in its repository.

1.-Add the Supervisor PPA repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:schooltool-owners/trunk
```

If the apt-add-repository binary doesn't exist then add it from the existing universe.

1.a (may be necessary) source:https://askubuntu.com/questions/38021/how-to-add-a-ppa-on-a-server

```
 sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
 sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

2.- Install Supervisor using apt-get

```
 sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

3.-Check the init.d directory for a script. You should get something like this:

```
    #! /bin/sh
    #
    # skeleton  example file to build /etc/init.d/ scripts.
    #       This file should be used to construct scripts for /etc/init.d.
    #
    #       Written by Miquel van Smoorenburg <miquels@cistron.nl>.
    #       Modified for Debian
    #       by Ian Murdock <imurdock@gnu.ai.mit.edu>.
    #               Further changes by Javier Fernandez-Sanguino <jfs@debian.org>
    #
    # Version:  @(#)skeleton  1.9  26-Feb-2001  miquels@cistron.nl
    #
    ### BEGIN INIT INFO
    # Provides:          supervisor
    # Required-Start:    $remote_fs $network $named
    # Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $network $named
    # Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
    # Default-Stop:      0 1 6
    # Short-Description: Start/stop supervisor
    # Description:       Start/stop supervisor daemon and its configured
    #                    subprocesses.
    ### END INIT INFO

    . /lib/lsb/init-functions

    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
    DAEMON=/usr/bin/supervisord
    NAME=supervisord
    DESC=supervisor

    test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

    LOGDIR=/var/log/supervisor
    PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
    DODTIME=5                   # Time to wait for the server to die, in seconds
                                # If this value is set too low you might not
                                # let some servers to die gracefully and
                                # 'restart' will not work

    # Include supervisor defaults if available
    if [ -f /etc/default/supervisor ] ; then
        . /etc/default/supervisor
    fi
    DAEMON_OPTS="-c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf $DAEMON_OPTS"

    set -e

    running_pid()
    {
        # Check if a given process pid's cmdline matches a given name
        pid=$1
        name=$2
        [ -z "$pid" ] && return 1
        [ ! -d /proc/$pid ] &&  return 1
        (cat /proc/$pid/cmdline | tr "\000" "\n"|grep -q $name) || return 1
        return 0
    }

    running()
    {
    # Check if the process is running looking at /proc
    # (works for all users)

        # No pidfile, probably no daemon present
        [ ! -f "$PIDFILE" ] && return 1
        # Obtain the pid and check it against the binary name
        pid=`cat $PIDFILE`
        running_pid $pid $DAEMON || return 1
        return 0
    }

    force_stop() {
    # Forcefully kill the process
        [ ! -f "$PIDFILE" ] && return
        if running ; then
            kill -15 $pid
            # Is it really dead?
            [ -n "$DODTIME" ] && sleep "$DODTIME"s
            if running ; then
                kill -9 $pid
                [ -n "$DODTIME" ] && sleep "$DODTIME"s
                if running ; then
                    echo "Cannot kill $LABEL (pid=$pid)!"
                    exit 1
                fi
            fi
        fi
        rm -f $PIDFILE
        return 0
    }

    case "$1" in
      start)
        echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE \
            --startas $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
        test -f $PIDFILE || sleep 1
            if running ; then
                echo "$NAME."
            else
                echo " ERROR."
            fi
        ;;
      stop)
        echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDFILE 
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;
      force-stop)
        echo -n "Forcefully stopping $DESC: "
            force_stop
            if ! running ; then
                echo "$NAME."
            else
                echo " ERROR."
            fi
        ;;
      #reload)
        #
        #   If the daemon can reload its config files on the fly
        #   for example by sending it SIGHUP, do it here.
        #
        #   If the daemon responds to changes in its config file
        #   directly anyway, make this a do-nothing entry.
        #
        # echo "Reloading $DESC configuration files."
        # start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 1 --quiet --pidfile \
        #   /var/run/$NAME.pid --exec $DAEMON
      #;;
      force-reload)
        #
        #   If the "reload" option is implemented, move the "force-reload"
        #   option to the "reload" entry above. If not, "force-reload" is
        #   just the same as "restart" except that it does nothing if the
        #   daemon isn't already running.
        # check wether $DAEMON is running. If so, restart
        start-stop-daemon --stop --test --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE \
            --startas $DAEMON \
        && $0 restart \
        || exit 0
        ;;
      restart)
        echo -n "Restarting $DESC: "
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDFILE
        [ -n "$DODTIME" ] && sleep $DODTIME
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE \
            --startas $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;
      status)
        echo -n "$LABEL is "
        if running ;  then
            echo "running"
        else
            echo " not running."
            exit 1
        fi
        ;;
      *)
        N=/etc/init.d/$NAME
        # echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload}" >&2
        echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status|force-stop}" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac

    exit 0
```

More details here:
https://github.com/Supervisor/initscripts

and here:
http://supervisord.org/running.html